# How to lock/block Safe Mode from standard user account?

Tags: startup, administrator, safe-mode

Is there a way to prevent a standard user from signing into safe mode and only allow the admin of my mac to boot/sign into safe mode?

Comment: Isn't safe mode accessed during the start up process and not via an account?

Comment: Once I boot into Safe Mode by holding down the Shift key, the I can choose which account to sign into. The options I see are the admin account and the standard account. I'm hoping there's a way to prevent sign in to the standard account.

Comment: Then it should have a password - all my accounts do.

Comment: Correct, but I don't want the standard user to be able to sign into their account even with their password. So to be more specific, on my mac there are two users, one is the admin and one is the standard. I only want the admin user to be able to sign into his account, and not the standard user into his.

Comment: What are you hoping to gain by allowing the standard user to use standard mode yet not safe mode?